# Array as a pointer

Tags: c++, c

```
int main()
{
   int x[2][2][2]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
   printf("%d%d%d%d",&x,&*x,&**x,&***x);
}
```

> output displayed is -28 -28 -28 -28.
>   Can someone please expalin this scenerio.address of a is -28.and it is pointing to -28.what is this.please explain with a diagram if possible.

Comment: You should demonstrate minimal understanding of the problem.. Share your thoughts please.

Comment: What is your code doing? If it were understandable, we may be able to help!

Comment: 1. Post actual code, not something made up. 2. Print pointers as pointers. 3. *An array is not a pointer*.

Comment: Uh, `a` is undefined in question code as far as I can see. So output should be what you describe (or anything, except compiler error).

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: oh god sorry guys for my mistake in place of a there is 'x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are the same but the type of them are not the same as shown below.
You first have to be aware that an expression of type "n elements array of of type T" is decayed
into a "pointer of type T" with exceptions of when array is an operand to &, sizeof operator, or a string literal.

Expression

```
&a  // type is  int(*)[2][2][2]
&*a // type is int(*)[2][2]
&**a // type is int(*)[2]
&***a // type is int  *
```

In above cases you are always using `&` operator which means expression will not decay to "pointer of type T" as explained earlier.
Note that the output of all will be same but their types are different, and output will be the base address of the array. Below is the distinction, if you write

```
int (*p)[2][2][2] = &a; // note types are same as shown above
//print p here
```

now if you do

```
p++;
printf("%p",p);
```

Notice difference between the two values of `p`. Then you must notice that `p` skips the whole array, that is all 8 elements.
And if you do

```
int (*q)[2][2] =  &*a;    // note types are same
```

Is same as

```
int(*q)[2][2] = &a[0];
```

After that you do

```
q++;
```

Then print `q` and notice difference between values of original `q` and updated `q`. You will find that it now points to 4 location next in memory.
So here the difference comes in.
Also change `%d` to `%p` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the depth of array-pointer decay. What happens is this:

1. The type of `x` is a 3D array, `int ()[2][2][2]`.
2. If you take its address, nothing special happens, you get a pointer to that array, i. e. `&x` has the type `int (*)[2][2][2]`.
3. However, in most other contexts, arrays are not used directly, they first *decay into a pointer to their first element*. So, in the expression `*x`, `x` first decays into a pointer of type `int (*)[2][2]` (the first element of a 3D array is a 2D array). Then this pointer is dereferenced to yield the 2D array `int ()[2][2]`.
4. Since the first slice of a 3D array is stored first, its address is the same as the address of the 3D array. I. e. `&x` and `&*x` yield the same address.
5. The same thing happens when you dereference a second time `&**x` gives you the address of the first line in the 3D array (its type is `int (*)[2]`).
6. Again, the same thing happens when you dereference a third time, `&***x` is the address of the first element in the array (its type is `int*`).

The mechanism of array-pointer decay allows C to define the array subscript operator strictly in terms of pointer arithmetic. The point is, that each of the three array types involved has a different size, which allows the compiler to deduce the correct offset. I. e. `sizeof(*x)` is `4*sizeof(int)` (remember the type of `*x` is `int ()[2][2]`), `sizeof(**x)` is `2*sizeof(int)`. Consequently, `x[1][0]` and `x[0][1]` resolve to two different line arrays in the 3D array.

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier `%d` is used for type `int`. You give it some other type and, thus, the behavior of your program is undefined. You might want to try `%p` (although it will probably show a similar result, at which point you'll need to start understanding what pointers are about).